# System.Interactivity.Behaviors - multiple?

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to attach multiple Behaviors to an UIElement (which, just judging from the the name of the Behaviors class should work). However, I can't find any documentation on the MSDN regarding this topic. Anybody who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Behaviors` is a collection you can arbitrarily add to it:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
     <local:Behavior1 />
     <local:Behavior2 />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

In code you first have to **get** the collection, then you can add to it, you do not set the `Behaviors` property itself.

Comment: Okay, I was just copying code from two of my xaml files, so I didn't see that I used an attached behavior - god knows why. Thanks!